# How can I mask an image with SVG and add a color stroke around the masked portion?

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I am using an external svg file and applying a mask from the file to an image on my web page. The mask is working well, but I'd like to have a colored stroke around the mask. I can't figure out how to add just a shape in an external svg file and how to apply that with CSS.

Right now the mask has a semi transparent stroke to kind of illustrate the size of the stroke I would like with color.

How could I add this?

Thanks

External SVG File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <mask id="m1"  x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".45" style="stroke:#909; stroke-width:.05; fill: #ffffff"/>
    </mask>

</svg>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>test mask</title>
<style> 
body {
background-color:LightBlue;
}
.masked {

    mask: url(svg/filters.xml#m1);

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item">
<a href="#">
<img class="masked" src="http://i.imgur.com/nSdiEn3.jpg"/>

</a>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You might be able to use the stroke method on your mask, i have never tried it but here is what the code looks like. <path stroke="blue" d="M5 40 l215 0" /> Try changing the path to mask and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create another path with the dimensions of the masked portion with:
fill-opacity="0.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"

(replace stroke and stroke-width with the desired values)